# Why no SSL certificate trust store at the user level?

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, tls

Most OSes have a global trust store (e.g., [`/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store). However, this method requires root to modify, and affects all users.

Most applications have a way to trust certificates at an application-level (e.g., `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` and Java's `keytool`). However, there is no single method that sets all applications to trust a certain SSL key.

Is there a way for a normal user to trust a certain SSL certificate for all applications that user runs? Why not? This seems easy to build and quite necessary for users of shared infrastructure who may want to trust something that other users do not.

The use case: I am working on a corporate IT network that uses HTTPS interception (like MITM), but they don't configure the OS certificate store to trust their cert. I do not have root on the corporate server. So far, I have been configuring things manually for Python's `requests`, Python's `urllib`, Java, cURL, wget, Firefox, Docker, git, ... but it is getting tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for a normal user to trust a certain SSL certificate for all applications that user runs?

Usually not. Which trust store is used depends on TLS stack defaults, library defaults, application defaults, application configuration ...

> This seems easy to build and quite necessary for users of shared infrastructure who may want to trust something that other users do not.

If it seems to be easy - just do it. You will be confronted with different file formats for trust stores and you will need to synchronize between all the different libraries, applications and settings. It is not that every developer deliberately wants to be incompatible with the rest, but often the existing defaults don't work properly for a specific use case so that the developers need to do their own thing - which is usually not the same thing as others do.

There are actually efforts underway to harmonize these things, like [Using Shared System Certificate](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/using-shared-system-certificates/)s in Fedora. But, there does not seem to be any considerations for user specific settings here, so this only helps with some use cases.

> ...  but it is getting tedious

Yes, unfortunately this is the current state.